# Content Script Warning, Unexpected Property Found (Firefox WebExtensions)

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

After typing out a tutorial code and adjusting the details/regex as follows:

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name" : "Paige",
    "version" : "1.0",

    "description" : "Gathers and displays a custom web feed",
    
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"],
            "js": ["paige.js"]
        }
    ],

    "permissions" : [
        "*://*.google.com/*"
    ]
}
```

I proceed to `about:debugging` and click `Load Temporary Add-on...`. I then select this manifest from my computer (which does indeed share a folder with a `paige.js`. This results in the following message:

```
Reading manifest: Warning processing content_script: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest.
```

I have double-checked with the tutorial *and* with the documentation, but I can't seem to determine the problem. The only related help I could find on this subject addressed the following error:

```
Reading manifest: Error processing content_script: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest.
```

This is not the same issue (as far as I can tell) given that mine is a warning and theirs is an error. Regardless, I checked the listed solution and it was not relevant. If anyone can help me discover my mistake, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is two-fold.

1. My issue was apparently a file-explorer issue, such that when I saved my file it saved to a new location rather than applying the changes to the original file location. This has now been resolved.
2. As far as the `Warning vs. Error` semantics go, they seem to be identical after all. For those wondering, this can be resolved by changing `"content_script"` to `"content_scripts"`.

Comment: These kind of problems don't warrant an answer because it's a typo.